# how to create a matrix from specific rows of different dataframes in r

Tags: r, list, matrix, vector

I have two data frames, let call them `df1` and `df2`. with the same dimension and titles for both dataframes. df1 is filled with humidity records and df2 is filled with temperature records.
first two columns are city codes and city names. the rest of the columns are numeric observations. ( this holds for both data frame )
I am going to create a list of matrices. these matrices are going to be constructed as :
`mat1` = the  numeric data of first row of `df1` and the  numeric data of first row of `df2`
`mat2` = the  numeric data of the 2nd row of `df1` and the  numeric data of the 2nd row of `df2`
and so on for all rows.
I do not need city codes and names in my matrices, but I would want to be able to know what matrix belongs to what city later from the list of matrices.

```
mylist <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
mylist[[i]] <- matrix(c(df1[i,-c(1,2)], df2[i,-c(1,2)]), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
}
```

I get : ****Error in mylist[[i]] <- matrix(c(dc[i, -c(1, 2)], dth[i, -c(1, 2)]), nrow = 2,  :
more elements supplied than there are to replace****

I need help with this please.

Comment: Try initializing it as `mylist <- list()` instead of `mylist <- 0`. Also is `byrow=TRUE` needed here?

Comment: thank you! solved :)